# Work hours dynamics crm 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'd like to set new appointments to default to start of work day for the currently logged-in user in dynamics 2013 (on premises if it matters).

Is there any way to do a query against the user's work hours via JavaScript, or do I need to do this with a plugin as in the SDK example, or is there some other way to accomplish this without custom code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If the work hours are stored in CRM...
You can use [rest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279.aspx), the [sdk.soap.js](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SdkSoapjs-9b51b99a), [JCL](https://github.com/paul-way/JCL) or another JavaScript library to query the work hours for the user.

If not stored in CRM but stored elsewhere, you have a few options (plugin, JSONP, etc.)

Lastly, if you can deduce the logic based on the user attributes/roles, you can do this via JavaScript.

Any approach will lead to having JavaScript on the form load setting the default time.  [Make sure to check the form type.](https://brucemisc.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/crm-2011-javascript-check-form-type/)